# skipping incompatible when searching for -lgpstk

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying "make" command on my linux to create an exe file, but I keep getting an error

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../../shared/gpstk/src/libgpstk.a when searching for -lgpstk
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgpstk
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   ../../../shared/makehome/common.makefile:79: recipe for target '../../../shared/binflate/src/binflate' failed

I have tried to download libraries through search online but I can't seem to get past this error. Can someone please help me out.

Here is the makefile code:

```
TARGET        = linux

#----------------------------------------------------------------- Directories
# Where make will put outputs and intermediate files
SVNROOTDIR    = ../../..
OBJDIR        = $(SVNROOTDIR)/obj
BINDIR        = $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/binflate/src
LIBDIR        = $(BINDIR)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------- Outputs
# What we are trying to build:
# Note: If you want this makefile to build an EXECUTABLE, leave LIBRARY 
#       undefined, and vice versa if you want to build a static LIBRARY
EXECUTABLE    = $(BINDIR)/binflate
LIBRARY       = 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------- Sources
SOURCES       = $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/basetime.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/parameters.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/report.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/datalog.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/util.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/serialutil.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/signaltype.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/channeltype.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/gridframework.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/binhelper.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/observables.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/txid.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/src/ReportWrapper.cpp \
        $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/binflate/src/binflate.cpp 

# include directories in gcc format
INCL          = -I../include \
        -I$(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/core/include  \
        -I$(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/gpstk/include 

# Libraries
LIBS          = -lm -lgpstk

# Library include directories in gcc format (-Lpath/to/dir1 -Lpath/to/dir2)
INCLLIB       = -L$(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/gpstk/src \
        -L/usr/local/lib

# Predefine macros
PREDEFINES    = 

#------------------------------------ Compilers, linkers, etc. and their flags
CC            = g++
CCFLAGS       = -g -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas \
        -Wno-uninitialized $(PREDEFINES)

CCINCL        = $(INCL) 

LIBEXE        = ar
LIBFLAGS      = rcs
LIBINCL       =

LNKEXE        = g++
LNKFLAGS      =
LNKINCL       = 

MD            = g++
MDFLAGS       = -MM
MDINCL        = $(INCL)


#---------------------------------------------------------- Included Makefiles
include $(SVNROOTDIR)/shared/makehome/common.makefile
```

Comment: Very likely, the library in question is incompatible because its contents are built for a different architecture than the program you're building is.  For example, they may be built for 32-bit x86, while you are building a 64-bit x86_64 binary.  Anyway, I cannot imagine why you would install random libraries you find on the Internet.  At minimum, obtain a source distribution and build a copy appropriate for your system.  Ideally, use your distro's package management system (yum / apt / etc.) to install an appropriate version of the library from a trusted source.

Comment: Seems to be that you are trying to link a 32bit lib into a 64bit compiled program or the other way around.